# Change mail recipients email address conditionally with vba

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

I have a button on my Access subform, that creates a new email based on a specific template depending on the value in a combo box. Most of these templates already have an existing To: email address.
This has to be replaced to the email address in the parent form of the subform in most cases (and that is being done with the current code) but if the value of the combo box is, say either 'x' or 'y' then it should insert another email in a second form where the main form and second form have linked fields.
The code that I have so far:

```
    If Me![cboEmail].Value = "Your patient Initial" Then
oMail.To = Nz(DLookup("[strEmail]", "tblAddress", "[longDoctorID] = " & Me.Parent!longDoctorID))
ElseIf Me![cboEmail].Value = "Follow Up of your patient" Then
oMail.To = Nz(DLookup("[strEmail]", "tblAddress", "[longDoctorID] = " & Me.Parent!longDoctorID))
Else
oMail.To = Me.Parent![strEmailAddress].Value
End If
```

What does not work is the first two conditions, where the value is "Your patient initial" or if it is "Follow Up of your patient"
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly *does not work*?

Answer (score 0):

```
[longDoctorID] = " & Me.Parent!longDoctorID)
```

Is this a string or an integer? If it's a string it needs to include two single. quotes

I don't understand the reason for `Nz` when you haven't specified the empty value? You are then trying to send an email To ""

```
Debug.print Me![cboEmail].Value
```

What does it give you?

Comment: @Andre & Dave, Thanks for your answer.
[longDoctorID] = " & Me.Parent!longDoctorID gives an integer
I am an end user in DIY mode where I regularly update my database with functionality as and when I need it. So with this code, in the condition where Your Patient Initial or Follow up of your patient is selected, an email based on selected template opens but the To: field contains the default email address of the template, whereas if it is any other value, the To: field contains the correct email address of the current record.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry guys, you were right in asking the question of what does not work? Because it was working code! When I put in the Debug.Print line, it gave an empty value because there was no value in the original table and therefore was giving the default email address.
Sorry to have used up your time. That original code works. Thanks for looking into the issue.